# Cannot upload image by carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, sidekiq, carrierwave-backgrounder

I am using carrierwave to upload my image but failed. Please help me.

Versions used:

```
rails (4.0.1)
carrierwave (0.10.0)
carrierwave-mongoid (0.7.1)
carrierwave_backgrounder (0.4.1)
```

My uploader:

```
#<EventImageUploader:0x007fc6a948ede8 
@model=#<Event::EventImage 
_id: 5876f63b6c616cea34630000, 
c_at(created_at): 2017-01-12 03:21:31 UTC, 
image: nil, 
image_tmp: "1484191291-59956-9524/2016-12-10_23-45.jpg">,
@mounted_as=:image>
```

My image is `nil`, but the image under `image_tmp` exists. My sidekiq is running fine too.

Here is my worker:

```
class ImageWorker < ::CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset
  def perform(*args)
    super(*args)

    record = ::CarrierWave::Workers::Base.perform(*args)
    if record 
      p "success"
    else
      raise "record #{args} not found, failed"
    end

  end
end
```

How to make the upload works? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing the source of `CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset#perform`,
the reason why the image cannot be uploaded is because of embedded documents.

The line from source `record = resource.find id` will return `nil` because `resource` is an embedded class and you cannot find id by an embedded class.

To solve the problem, see [here](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder#uploaders-mounted-on-mongoid-embedded-documents). My code should work if I add the following:

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :images
end

class EventImage
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :Event

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  process_in_background :image

  def self.find(id)
    bson_id = Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string(id) # needed for Mongoid 3

    root = Event.where('images._id' => bson_id).first
    root.images.find(id)
  end
end
```

If you get the error `uninitialized constant Moped::BSON`, make sure to `require` it in the first place.